# Initialise custom class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Initially, I have a function that looks like this

```
import { CustomDate } from './../models/customDate';

export class DateService {

    datePickerResultToDate(date: Date) {

        var myDate: CustomDate;

        var month_str: string;

        switch (date.getMonth()) {
            case 0:
                month_str = 'Jan';
                break;
            case 1:
                month_str = 'Feb';
                break;
            // etc...
            default:
                month_str = 'Some Error';
        }

        myDate.day = date.getDate();
        myDate.month = date.getMonth();
        myDate.year = date.getFullYear();
        myDate.customDateString = date.getDate().toString() + ' ' + month_str + ' ' + date.getFullYear().toString();

        return myDate
    }

}
```

where

```
export class CustomDate {
    day: number;
    month: number;
    year: number;
    customDateString: string;
}
```

Upon execution, I am getting this error

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./TimeSheetComponent class TimeSheetComponent - inline template:16:8 caused by: Cannot set property 'day' of undefined

So I figured I needed to change to

```
    var myDate: CustomDate = {
        day: 0,
        month: 0,
        year: 0,
        customDateString: ''
    }
```

and that fixes it. My question is, it is seems very odd to initialise myDate ti those values every time I want to use it. Is there a way to simplify this so that when I want to use myDate, it is already initialised and ready to use? Or do I have to do this every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got that error because you haven't initalized `CustomDate` class, you only made `myDate` variable as type of `CustomDate`. Rather you should have instantiate object of `CustomDate`

```
var myDate: CustomDate = new CustomDate();
```

**OR**

To reduce your effort while instantiating class, you can move all common stuff inside class, though you just need to pass `Date` object to `CustomDate` constructor.

```
export class CustomDate {
    day;
    month;
    year;
    customDateString: Date;
    constructor(Date date) {
       this.day = date.getDate();
       this.month = date.getMonth();
       this.year = date.getFullYear();
       this.customDateString = date.getDate().toString() + ' ' + month_str + ' ' + date.getFullYear().toString();

    }
}
```

then do something like below.

```
var myDate: CustomDate = new CustomDate(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a constructor to your CustomDate class and initialize the default values. So you need not initialize it when using. Your class can be:

```
export class CustomDate {
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
  customDateString: string;

  constructor() {
    this.day = 0;
    this.month = 0;
    this.year = 0;
    this.customDateString = '';
  }
}
```